# TF-IDF Features vs Embedding Layer

Tags: keras, nlp, rnn, tfidf

Have you guys tried to compare the performance of TF-IDF features* with a shallow neural network classifier vs a deep neural network models like an RNN that has an embedding layer with word embedding as weights next to the input layer? I tried this on a couple of tweet datasets and got surprising results: f1 score of~65% for the TF-IDF vs ~45% for the RNN. I tried the setup embedding layer + shallow fully connected layer vs TF-IDF + fully connected layer but got almost same result difference. Can you guys give some opinion on how TF-IDF features can outperform the embedding layer of a deep NN? Is this case common? Thanks!

- I've used unigrams and bigrams to produce the TF-IDF features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common for TFIDF to be a strong model. People constantly get high places in Kaggle competitions with TFIDF models. Here is a link to the winning solution that used TFIDF as one of its features ([1st place Otto product classification](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/discussion/14335)). You will most likely get a stronger model if you combine the TFIDF and RNN into one ensemble. Other results from Kaggle:

- 2nd place: https://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/discussion/6184
- 4th place: https://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-demand-prediction/discussion/59881
- 3rd place: https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge/discussion/52762

https://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-demand-prediction/discussion/56897:

> A good number of kernels are going the traditional route with
>   CountVectorizer/TF-IDF, and some brave souls (I say brave because
>   training is slower and the results don't seem as spectacular so far)
>   have been experimenting with embeddings, as per the previous
>   competitions.